# What makes TextMate a good editor?

Tags: text-editor, emacs, textmate, software-recommendation

I'm always reading about developers praising TextMate as *the* editor. What's so awesome about it?

Please note that I'm a long-term Emacs user.

Comment: Stick with Emacs, TextMate wishes it was as good.

Answer (score 1):

[Download a free 30-day trial](http://macromates.com/) and find out.  The site goes into detail on all of the features listed below but these are the main features.

- Ability to Search and Replace in a Project
- Auto-Indent for Common Actions Like Pasting Text
- Auto-Pairing of Brackets and Other Characters
- Clipboard History
- Column Selections and Column Typing
- Completion of Words from Current Document
- CSS-like Selectors to Pinpoint the Scope of Actions and Settings
- Declarative Language Grammars for Graceful Mixing and Hacking
- Dynamic Outline for Working With Multiple Files
- Expand Trigger Words to Code Blocks With Tab-able Placeholders
- File Tabs when Working With Projects
- Foldable Code Blocks
- Function Pop-up for Quick Overview and Navigation
- Plug-able Through Your Favorite Scripting Language
- Recordable Macros With No Programming Required
- Regular Expression Search and Replace (grep)
- Run Shell Commands from Within a Document
- Support for Darcs, Perforce, SVK, and Subversion
- Support for More Than 50 Languages
- Switch Between Files in Projects With a Minimum of Key Strokes
- Themable Syntax Highlight Colors
- Visual Bookmarks to Jump Between Places in a File
- Works As External Editor for (s)ftp Programs
- Works Together With Xcode and Can Build Xcode Projects

Comment: I would recommend download the beta of version 2. Other points are that it is not blown up with useless fancy graphics and is *extremely* fast. I couldn't live without TextMate...